# Recover data from old machine and external hard drive

Tags: ntfs, data-recovery

that is long dead. Motherboard issues, not worth repairing
I want to salvage what I can, so I pulled out the hard drive, popped it into an enclosure, and try look at it from my laptop.

The problem being that I start hitting permission issues. I changed the ownership of the drive to my current user, and now I cant see anything. it looks like my drive is empty.

if I launch comand prompt as administrator, and I do a Dir, it lists the first file on the root (which I couldnt see in explorer), then "File Not Found" and stops the dir.

Any suggestions?

Edit: If I use Piriform Recuva I get an error: "Unable to determine file system type"

Comment: Can you try with these instructions? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31377/19806 If they work for you I can summarize them in an answer.

Comment: Did you try the instructions in the link?